# In a rector rule's refactor function, how to print the current node as code?

Tags: rector

Having a `Node` in the `refactor` function of a rule, how can I print the full node as php code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found !

Install, using composer, the package `rector/rector-debugging`

Then there is available some helpers.

The one I needed was `print_node`.